# How fgets() really works to read from stdin?

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

So if I have to use `fgets()` twice to read two different input from the keyboard, should I specify two different buffers or just reuse the same one? What's the difference?

Use the same buffer:

```
   char buffer[100];
   fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
   fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

Use the different buffers for different inputs:

```
   char buffer_x[100];
   char buffer_y[100];
   fgets(buffer_x , sizeof(buffer_x), stdin);
   fgets(buffer_y , sizeof(buffer_y), stdin);
```

Comment: In the first sample, the second input will overwrite the first input. That's the difference.

Comment: If code needs the result of the first to be preserved after reading the second, then use different buffers.

Comment: BTW, check the return value of `fgets()` before using the buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on your use-case. Both the usage maybe equally valid or invalid based on the retention requirement of your logic.

- In case, the control flow of your program is something like

  ```
  read first input
   process first input, never need it after this
  read second input
   carry on
  ```

  then you're okay with the first approach, reusing the same buffer.
- In case, you have to make use of the first input even after reading the second one, you need to preserve the first input, like

  ```
  read first input
   process first input, but need it later also
  read second input
   carry on 
   do something with first and second inputs
  ```

  then, you need separate buffers.